# How to know if LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation) is applicable to a particular problem?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

Suppose my database has many tables and each table has many columns. I want to use column names of all tables to figure out "major data contents" in my database. Example columns are monthly_spend_amount, last_name, country. monthly_spend_amount is converted into the text like "monthly spend amount" before further processing. How to determine if LDA can be used for this task given that each text will has only 1 to 3 words.